# php generate all possible values of characters

Tags: php

I would like a function to generate all possible combination of alphabets. The only parameter the function would need is the number of characters. So for instance if I pass '2', it'll generate:

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
..
..
zz
```

If I pass 3, it'll generate:

```
aaa
aab
...
...
aaz
...
zzz
```

And so on if I pass 4, etc. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You are aware that what you're asking for will result in exponential performance and memory usage, right?  For example for 1 letter you'll be executing a loop 26 times and using 26 bytes of memory (not counting PHP var overhead) but for 8 letters will require 208,827,064,576 runs through the loop and 208,827,064,576 bytes of memory consumed

Comment: Yes aware, but it'll probably need to go till 4 characters only.

Comment: Have you actually tried to implement it?  If so, can you share some code?

Comment: I tested at 4 with recursion and no array allocation needed and it is very bad on the browser. The browser hangs. See my implementation below. I don't think the memory is bad rather then output is huge as @GordonM suggests. :) This is probably not a good idea to actually do in practice but was a semi-interesting recursion problem.

Comment: Why the down voting on Patrick? Seems legit question to me. Silly folks hatin'.

Answer (score 12):

All these complex nested loops, or use of recursion are totally unnecessary.

Simply use the ++ incrementor with characters.

```
$string = 'a';
while ($string != 'aaaaa') {
    echo $string++,PHP_EOL;
}
```

Just watch out for your end loop test... use a != rather than < or > type comparisons

**EDIT**

So to give you the function you want:

```
function combinations($size) {
    $string = str_repeat('a',$size);
    $endLoopTest = str_repeat('z',$size);
    $endLoopTest++;
    while ($string != $endLoopTest) {
        echo $string++,PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are a smooth operator sir. +1 is all I am allowed to give you. :) I'm modifying my title to "Mark Baker's answer is the real one".

Comment: A great answer indeed. I never knew it was possible to increment a character like that. I thought that was only possible for numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in theory, this works. I couldn't put my computer through the torture of testing it though.

```
function combinations($pass, $count = null, $l = ''){
    if(is_null($count)) $count = $pass;
    foreach(range('a','z') as $c){
        $k = $l;
        $k .= $c;
        if($count == 1){
            echo $k;
        }else{
            combinations($pass, $count-1, $k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a funny question huh? Who in their right mind would actually do this in production? :)

Comment: @emeraldcode.com I dunno, but I could see uses in this for populating a static file. Nice solution btw, your code is cleaner than mine :D

Comment: Its probably because I didn't know about foreach and range. I was doing it old school as I just looked up chr as I was too lazy to type out an array. :) Anyway, +1 to you sir.

Comment: @emeraldcode - Think of spreadsheet column IDs, and you have one possible answer to why it might be done in a production system

Answer (score 2):

See Mark Baker's answer as its the real one. Mine is overly complex not understanding PHP as I don't code in it. Plus, he is just smarter at it seems. :)

```
<?php 

        function alphabetCombos($length,$prefix = '') {
            for($j = 97; $j < 123; $j++) {
                if ($length > 1) {
                    alphabetCombos($length-1,$prefix . chr($j));
                } else {
                    echo $prefix . chr($j) . '<br />';
                }
            }
        }

        alphabetCombos(2);
?>
```

Comment: If you change it to `function alphabetCombos($length, $prefix = '')` It will work the same, and meet the question's requirement of having to input only one value (the length).

Comment: Thanks @Grexis . I don't actually code in PHP so didn't know the default value. That's pretty interesting to know though so good call.

Comment: @Mark Baker, Ḯ'm just curious: What's wrong with the ++ incrementor?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the ++ incrementor, aside from the fact that most people only believe it works with numbers... you can increment characters as well, making it a whole lot easier to generate the OPs sequence

Answer (score -1):

I can tell u the logic of two words.. you can apply for the rest

```
foreach ( range('a','z') as $f)
 {
      foreach ( range('a','z') as $s)
      {
          echo "<br/>".$f.$s;
      }
}
```

reference : [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: for 3 letter's combination; apply one more `foreach`

Comment: You should use the string `'a'`, not rely on PHP's fallback for undefined constants.

Comment: Hint: Recursion can be used here for more flexibility.

Comment: @diEcho: Your code is relying on a misfeature of PHP.  It's attempting to find a constant called a and another one called z.  As it fails to find them it then assumes that they're actually strings (so your code works), but it also generates a warning which will be visible in the output if display_errors is turned on.  More importantly, if a constant called a or z really is defined somewhere then there's no telling what your code will do.

Comment: @recursion or nested loops are both unnecessary